# In Visual Studio 2013 C++ I have clearly defined a class and am receiving errors saying that it is not a class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, compiler-errors

This is my header file for the class (mesh)

```
#ifdef MESH_H
#define MESH_H
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <GL\glew.h>
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex(const glm::vec3& pos)
    {
        this->pos = pos;
    }
protected:
private:
    glm::vec3 pos;

};

class Mesh
{
public:
    Mesh(Vertex* vertices, unsigned int numVertices);

    void Draw();

    virtual ~Mesh();

protected:
private:
    Mesh(const Mesh& other);
    void operator = (const Mesh& other);

    enum 
    {
        POSITION_VB,

        NUM_BUFFERS
    }

    GLuint g_vertexArrayObject;
    GLuint g_vertexArrayBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS);
    unsigned int g_drawCount;
};
#endif
```

This is the main error I get. All of the other errors are based around this one.

```
Error 1 error C2653: 'Mesh' : is not a class or namespace name
```

Please help me as this makes no sense because I have clearly defined "mesh" as a class. Thanks

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: the line of my cpp file for the class when I use Mesh::Mesh() {}

Comment: yes I did include the header in the cpp file

Comment: Show the cpp file. Is that `C2653` the _first_ error during compilation?

Comment: yes it is the first error during compilation

Comment: voted to close as simple typographic error.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `int a, *b = a;` is one typo away from being compilable, yet it's not necessarily a _simple typographic error_.

Comment: @dxiv: Not sure where you're going with that observation. This question was about a missing `n`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf And my example was about a missing `&`. It's not obvious in the context that the OP mistyped `#ifndef` vs. misunderstood why `#ifndef` and actually meant to type `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 7):

Your class is not actually been defined.
I think `#ifdef MESH_H` should be `#ifndef MESH_H`